# How can i make a query that groups first column and attach any of the rows of second column within each group

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, orm

I new in sql and I have a postgresql database which has:

Table

| name1 | name2 | name3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group1 | subgroup_A | element1 |
| group1 | subgroup_B | element2 |
| group1 | subgroup_C | element3 |
| group2 | subgroup_D | element4 |
| group2 | subgroup_E | element5 |
| group2 | subgroup_F | element6 |
| group2 | subgroup_G | element7 |
| group3 | subgroup_H | element8 |
| group3 | subgroup_I | element9 |

I need to get just 3 rows from db
| name1 | name3

```
:-------|------------
|group1 | element1 (or element2, element3. it doesn`t matter)
|group2 | element4 (or element5 .. element7. it doesn`t matter)
|group3 | element8 (or element9. it doesn`t matter)
```

database has more than 300000 rows.

I tried to use:

```
select distinct name1 
from Table
```

I got

```
| name1 | 
:-------|------------
|group1
|group2
|group3
```

but how to add any of the name3 inside each group
What is the best way to do this in SQL and in 'django orm'?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use MAX() or MIN() to pick an element.

Comment: Thank you! The decision so simple..

Answer (score 0):

Using the technique mentionned by jarlh, you can use the following query :

```
SELECT name1, MAX(name3)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY name1
```

You can check it on the following [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5e5701abb5e9c3b6f4ead228054ff283).

Answer (score 0):

The concept of "it doesn't matter" really does not exist in SQL. The query needs to specify how to go about selecting what you want or not specify anything and take it all. That's what using Min or Max does. The issue though is without a date change you always get the same result. If that's what you actually want great, but if not you can simulate "it doesn't matter"; one way is using order by random. So: See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ee0307cf3f2e518584c3c7b828ba78f7)

```
select distinct on (name1)  
       name1,name3
  from atable
 order by name1, random() ;
```